# GridView with UpdatePanel OR DataTables with JQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I worked with java and jsp and have always used jquery , json data from serer side and custom HTML code with datatables . I have to work on a project with C# and I was introduced to GridView and AJAXControl Toolkit .

While reading some posts I learned that ASP.NET server controls are not exactly right way to work with web project but MVC is a better solution but learning curve so I am thinking to stick with webforms , use webmethods returning JSON , Jquery to call webmethods and binding it to DataTables . Is that a better approach than using Gridview and UpdatePanel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gridview/Update Panel approach:

**Pro:** Super easy to build

**Con:**  Results in uglier HTML (and extra javascript in the back), much more difficult to customize once in place.

MVC/jquery approach:

**Pro:** Very clean/lean HTML and javascript, easy to customize and maintain.

**Con:** Steeper learning curve, a few minutes longer to code assuming equal proficiency in both approaches.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Microsoft hasn't declared yet that MVC is better than WebForms. It's just a matter of what you like better. Second, I think that your idea of building a RESTful WCF Service that accepts and returns JSON is an incredible idea and very light-weight and easy to work with.

Comment: I'm agree with @Keyvan. It's just a matter of what you like better